# Python: How can I implement yield in my recursion?

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

How can I implement `yield from` in my recursion? I am trying to understand how to implement it but failing:

```
# some data
init_parent = [1020253]

df = pd.DataFrame({'parent': [1020253, 1020253],
                    'id': [1101941, 1101945]})
```

```
# look for parent child
def recur1(df, parents, parentChild=None, step=0):
    if len(parents) != 0:
        yield parents, parentChild

    else:
        parents = df.loc[df['parent'].isin(parents)][['id', 'parent']]
        parentChild = parents['parent'].to_numpy()
        parents = parents['id'].to_numpy()
        yield from recur1(df=df, parents=parents, parentChild=parentChild, step=step+1)
```

```
# exec / only printing results atm
out = recur1(df, init_parent, step=0)
[x for x in out]
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? What is you goal, to build the tree of parent -> child? Can you provide a more meaningful example?

Comment: I believe so and I would like to learn the yield implementation here; there is an undisclosed number of children for each parent where we need to look to see what we can find.

Comment: Can you update your example to be a bit more complex, and provide the expected output?

Comment: A bit more complex is relative ;)

Comment: let's say 10/15 rows max with 3/4 nested levels?

Comment: If you're using `yield from`, you should `yield` at some other point in the func, probably where you're `return`ing. But I have no idea what the specification or requirements are here.

Comment: Here is a slightly more complex example that could make it more clear what you want to achieve: `pd.DataFrame({'parent': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 'id': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your biggest issue here is that `recur1` isn't always guaranteed to return a generator. For example, suppose your stack calls into the `else` branch three times before calling into the `if` branch. In this case, the top three frames would be returning a generator received from the lower frame, but the lowest from would be returned from this:

```
yield parents, parentChild
```

So, then, there is a really simple way you can fix this code to ensure that `yield from` works. Simply transform your return from a tuple to a generator-compatible type by enclosing it in a list:

```
yield [(parents, parentChild)]
```

Then, when you call `yield from recur1(df=df, parents=parents, parentChild=parentChild, step=step+1)` you'll always be working with something for which `yeild from` makes sense.